# Parts Moving Through Tanks. Shortest Path Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, shortest-path

Suppose there is a production line with 8 tanks: each filled with a different substance for parts to be dipped in. The parts will be dropped into tanks by a crane along side the tanks. Each part moving through the tanks has a recipe associated with it. That is, each a part with recipe #1 must be in tank 1 for 10 seconds and tank 2 for 5 seconds and so on. Also each part must be dipped in each tank in the order of the tank numbers `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`.

Further suppose that each part cannot sit in a tank for more than the time specified in the recipe for that part and the travel time of the crane is instantaneous. For example if a part is in tank 2 for 10 seconds and the next part scheduled to enter tank 1 only is supposed to be in tank 1 for 5 seconds then that part will not be put in tank 1 because it would then have to wait in tank 1 for 5 seconds longer than the recipe specified. Instead the crane must wait to put a new part in tank 1 until it is guaranteed to not have any wait time moving between tanks.

Now if you have say 50 parts with recipe 1, 50 with recipe 2, and 50 with recipe 3 then what is the optimal way to add parts into the tanks? `1,1,1,2,3,2,1,3...`? or maybe all parts with recipe 1 first then a mix of parts 2 and 3? My most promising thought on maybe solving this problem is to use a shortest path algorithm (which I don't have much experience with), but Dijkstra's algorithm looked promising. I would build a tree where the root node is the first part put on the line and each child represents the next part to be put in the tanks. If you start with a part using recipe 1 then you can think of it as the root node with three children `1,2,3` (one for each type of recipe). Similarly each of those child nodes would have three children `1,2,3` and so on down the line until you've run out of parts to add to the tree. The 'distance' between a parent  and its child would then be how long, based on the parent's recipe, that the child has to wait outside the tanks before it can enter and safely move through the tanks with no delays.

The problem with this method, however, is that there are `150!/(50!)^3 = 2*10^64` distinct orders of part which would make it quite difficult to store in any kind of data structure or process it in a reasonable way. What other approaches could I take to solve this problem? Is a definitive optimal order of parts even obtainable or would I have to settle for an approximation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn this into a minimum cost flow problem.

- Use a starting node `s` with supply 150 (the sum of your amounts of parts)
- Add a node for each of your recipes
- Connect each of these nodes to `s` and give them a capacity of 50 (however many of that part you need)
- Add another node for each of your recipes, plus 1 extra.
- Connect each of your first recipe nodes to each of the nodes you've just created.
- Give these edges `(i,j)` infinite capacity, and a cost of how long you have to wait for recipe `j` to proceed before you can start recipe `i`. (For our special extra node, `0`, any edge `(i,0)` should have cost 0 (as though we started with this recipe).
- Connect each of these last nodes to a sink `t` with demand 150 (same as the supply of the source) using an edge with capacity 50 (or the amount of that part needed) or 1 (in the case of our special 0 node, since only 1 part can go first).

You can solve this problem with linear programming. What's nice about this approach is that you'll only have 2*n + 3 nodes and n*(n+3) + 1 edges, regardless of how many parts you have to produce.

### EDIT

The Linear Programming formulation is actually way easier than the network flow (to explain):

```
min sum(i in Recipes, sum(j in Recipes, t_(i,j)*n_(i,j)))
s.t. sum(j in Recipes n_(i,j)) = d_i for all i in Recipes
     sum(i in Recipes n_(i,j)) <= d_j for all j in Recipes
     sum(i in Recipes n_(i,0)) = 1
     n_(i,j) >= 0 for all i in Recipes, for all j in Recipes and 0
```

where `t_(i,j)` is the time we wait for recipe `j` to proceed before starting recipe `i`, and `n_(i,j)`is the number of parts of recipes type `i` that follow a part of recipe type `j`, and `n_(i,0)` represents the number of parts of recipes type `i` that don't follow anything (that go first). `d_i` is the number of parts of recipe `i` that should be made.

Comment: The idea with a minimum cost flow is that you send an amount through a network from the source `s` to the sink `t` obeying the capacities of the edges you traverse. The cost of the flow is the sum of the cost of each edge multiplied by how much is travelling along that edge.

Comment: I've picked up a book on network flow and have begun reading. I'm wholly unfamiliar with both network flow and linear programming. Should I drop network flow for now and instead read about linear programming?

Comment: I learned linear programming first. There are some network flow formulations that can be solved with specialized algorithms, but a lot of them (all?) can be solved with linear programming. It would probably be best to start with LP, and once you know the basics look at network flow theory (though, for this question it's about as easy to interpret it directly as an LP).

Comment: I've been reading some on Linear Programming. The book I'm looking at is quite confusing. All the problems at least in the first chapter involve using the book's included software to solve but alas it's an old book and the software was for windows 95 anyways. It seems the idea though is to solve for the decision variables: `n_(i,j)` but this would only give the number of parts of recipe 1 to go after recipe 2 for example. I'm interested in the ordering of all the parts. Technically you could reconstruct the order from this information, but it would be quite a bit of work. Is this the case?

Comment: That is correct. For software, see if AMPL will suit your purposes. As far as reconstructing the ordering, it should be quite easy. The naive approach (begin with the starting recipe, and proceed by attaching any recipe that can follow the preceding recipe until you run out) should be guaranteed to work. The only way it could fail is if you got to a point where there was no recipe left to follow the most recently appended recipe. So you ended with `i` and you've already followed `i` with `j` `n_(i,j)` times for all of your `j`'s.  But that means you've followed `i` `d_i` times already.

Comment: So your current arrangement has `d_i + 1` `i`'s. But by following the naive algorithm, this can't happen (you would have appended an `i` after you'd already run out of them).